# Creating Postscript function dictionary type 0

Tags: postscript

I am trying to create a Postscript function dictionary of type 0. The input is single dimension and the output is 3 dimension. 
Input 0 Output [ 0 0 0]
Input 1 Output [ 1 1 1]
I am having trouble writing the DataSource for this function dictionary. The PLRM manual says that DataSource has to be either a string or pure binary data. Can someone help me map these values to the format DataSource expects?

/FunctionType 0
/Domain [ 0 1 ]
/Range [ 0 1 0 1 0 1]
/Order 1
/BitsPerSample 8
/Size [ 2 ]
/DataSource ????

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to the PLRM, /DataSource is either a string or file.  Let's suppose your sample values are 0x00 and 0xFF.

For a string, use a hex string like this:

```
/DataSource <00FF>
```

The file method is more complicated and for two bytes of sample data would be inefficient.  I will not show that here unless you really need to read the data from a file.

Comment: I see. I am having trouble using this functionary dictionary for axial shading. I want to vary the shading from Color White to Color Black across the diagonal of a square. Can you please edit the function dictionary in original question to illustrate how that can be done?

Answer (score 2):

OK, based on your comment, here is how I have done this:

```
<< % Make gradient pattern dictionary
  /PatternType 2
  /Shading
  <<
    /ShadingType 2
    /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
    /Coords [ 0 0 72 72 ] % Set coord array (gradient starting point to ending point)
    /Function
    <<
      /FunctionType 2
      /Domain [ 0 1 ]
      /C0 [ 1 1 1 ] % Set color 1 (white in RGB space)
      /C1 [ 0 0 0 ] % Set color 2 (black in RGB space)
      /N 1
    >>
  >>
>>
matrix makepattern
```

This is for an example square at  `0,0  0,72  72,72  72,0`.